# Getting a crash with deallocated object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm getting a crash with this error message:  `2012-01-14 15:09:36.667 [8274:15203] *** -[ExerciseHistoryDetailViewController controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8d0e1f0`

Here is the code.  Any idea what's causing this?

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.historyTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.historyTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.historyTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.historyTableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.historyTableView endUpdates];
}
```

Edit, I got the app to crash again with the same workflow but the debug output is slightly different.

This time error is : `2012-01-14 17:35:48.793 [9012:15203] *** -[DetailViewController controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fb6100`

This is the line it crashed at: `(![managedObjectContext save:&error])` 
This is the method:

```
-(IBAction)createSet
{    
    Set *set = (Set *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Set" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [self.exercise addSetsObject:set];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    [self checkIfEmpty];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil; 
    [setsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860064/controllerwillchangecontent-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance

Comment: Well, the cause is that you (or the system, on your behalf) attempted to execute `controllerWillChangeContent` with a deleted object.  Presumably this means that your NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate instance got deleted.  Probably because you issued one release too many against it.

Comment: I'm using ARC so I'm not releasing anything...

Comment: @jonkroll that question's answer solved my crash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of situation, the fastest way to track down the culprit is to enable NSZombies. Read [here](http://on.iptorrents.com/details.php?id=559556) how to do it. With zombies enabled, your program should halt on the exact line causing the crash.

I have found a nice tutorial on how to debug memory problems on iOS [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial).

Comment: I ran the app again and put the updated console output in the question.